# I am getting an error while i am running a function in pandas dataframe.I am getting invalid syntax for the first line of the function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, lambda

def revised_price(engine-location,price):
if engine-location==front:
updated_price== price
else:
updated_price== 2*price

return new_profit

df['updated_price'] = df.apply(lambda x: revised_price(x['engine-location'], x['price']),axis=1)

Please find the error that i am getting
File "", line 1
def revised_price(engine-location,'price):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't follow naming convention here

You can't name inside a function like engine-location , instead rename it to engine_location, and also instead of

```py
updated_price == price
```

try

```py
updated_price = price
```

and instead of

```py
updated_price == 2*price
```

use

```py
updated_price = 2*price
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.This really worked

Comment: welcome , now please accept this as answer so that i can get reputation 